# Bash: Replace each occurrence of string in file with next value from array

Tags: bash, sed

I have an .yml file with three address entries and some other data, and an array containing three new addresses to replace these with

file.yml:

```
[...]
- address: s1.example.com
  user: ubuntu
  role: storage
- address: w1.example.com
  user: ubuntu
  role: worker
- address: w2.example.com
  user: ubuntu
  role: worker
[...]
```

array:

```
addr[0]: storage.domain.com
addr[1]: worker1.domain.com
addr[2]: worker2.domain.com
```

expected result:

```
[...]
- address: storage.domain.com
  user: ubuntu
  role: storage
- address: worker1.domain.com
  user: ubuntu
  role: worker
- address: worker2.domain.com
  user: ubuntu
  role: worker
[...]
```

I'm using `sed`, as I would like to write the new lines directly to the original file

I have tried a number of times, but the array incrementing always fails

#### Attempt 1

```sh
sed -i "s/- address: .*/- address: ${addr[$i]}/g" file.yml
```

This seems to exclusively write the first item in the array:

```
- address: storage.domain.com
[...]
- address: storage.domain.com
[...]
- address: storage.domain.com
[...]
```

#### Attempt 2

```sh
if (grep -e "- address:" file.yml); then
    sed -i "s/- address: .*/- address: ${addr[$i]}/g"
    ((i++))
fi
```

This seems to grep all results at the same time, and forwards nothing to `sed` as I haven't figured that one out yet.
Output:

```
  - address: s1.example.com
  - address: w1.example.com
  - address: w2.example.com
sed: no input files
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I started doing this with similar jobs:

- Print all array members with some separator, ex. `:`. Put this as the first input to `sed`.
- The first line (ie. the array members printed with some separator) are put into hold space
- Then for each the `- address:` found:

  - I copy the hold space into pattern space, extract the first element of the array  and append it with `- address :`. And print.
  - And remove the first element from hold space

The script below:

```
# replicate input
cat <<EOF >file.yml
[...]
- address: s1.example.com
  user: ubuntu
  role: storage
- address: w1.example.com
  user: ubuntu
  role: worker
- address: w2.example.com
  user: ubuntu
  role: worker
[...]
EOF

addr[0]=storage.domain.com
addr[1]=worker1.domain.com
addr[2]=worker2.domain.com

# the sed script
sed -nE '
  1{
    # hold the first line with array members separated with :
    H
    # don't print anything
    d
  }

  # if the line is address
  /- address: .*/{
    g
    s/\n//
    # remove all except first array member from hold space
    s/:.*//
    # prepend it with _- address_
    s/^/- address: /

    # remove the first member from hold space
    x
    s/[^:]*://
    x
  }
  # print the output
  p
' <( IFS=':'; printf "%s\n" "${addr[*]}"; ) file.yml
```

and the same oneliner:

```
sed -n '1{;H;d};/- address: .*/{g;s/\n//;s/:.*//;s/^/- address: /;x;s/[^:]*://;x};p' <( IFS=':'; printf "%s\n" "${addr[*]}"; ) file.yml
```

will output:

```
[...]
- address: storage.domain.com
  user: ubuntu
  role: storage
- address: worker1.domain.com
  user: ubuntu
  role: worker
- address: worker2.domain.com
  user: ubuntu
  role: worker
[...]
```

Comment: For me, it looks like this would scale really well when adding more entries to the array and file. Is this correct?

Comment: It would, correct, I guess that's the whole point. Care should be taken choosing the array separator. I just chose `:` for simplicity, but with ex. `\x01` you can get quite safe. Then you would have to change the `s/:.*//;` and `s/[^:]*://` commands.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is as follows:

```
addr=(storage.domain.com worker1.domain.com worker2.domain.com)
i=0
line_count=1
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line == *"- address:"* ]]; then
      sed -i "${line_count}s/- address: .*/- address: ${addr[i]}/" file.yml
      i=$((i+1))
    fi
    line_count=$((line_count+1))
done < file.yml
```

Above script iterates through the file, line by line and then replace the matching line with the content of the array.

Comment: This seems to have cleared every address but the first, which was set to worker2.domain.com

Comment: No, wait, I found the problem. There was a comment above the values which also had the text "address" in it

Comment: @Jabbl I tested it and worked for the sample input. Could you tell me, what problem did you face?

Comment: A comment just above my sample said this:
'# Add "internal_address: x"
# when changing "address" to external. '
Because of the wildcard search in your example, these two were also included

Comment: changing the wildcard to `*"- address:"*` should solve that issue. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /bin/bash

# initialise the array the way you want

addr[0]="storage.domain.com"
addr[1]="worker1.domain.com"
addr[2]="worker2.domain.com"

awk -F: -v addr="${addr[*]}" ' BEGIN{count=0 ; split(addr, addr_array, " ") }
{
    if( $1 ~ /address/ ) {

        for(i=1;i<=NF-1;++i){
            printf "%s:", $i
        }

        printf "%s\n", addr_array[++count]
    }
    else
    {
        print
    }

}' file.yml
```

If you want to overwrite the original file,

```
addr[0]="storage.domain.com"
addr[1]="worker1.domain.com"
addr[2]="worker2.domain.com"

gawk -i inplace -F: -v addr="${addr[*]}" ' BEGIN{count=0 ; split(addr, addr_array, " ") }
{
    if( $1 ~ /address/ ) {

        for(i=1;i<=NF-1;++i){
            printf "%s:", $i
        }

        printf "%s\n", addr_array[++count]
    }
    else
    {
        print
    }

}' file.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
printf ": %s\n" "${addr[@]}" |
sed '/address:/R /dev/stdin' ymlFile | 
sed '/address:/{N;s/:.*:/:/}'
```

Print the addr array out to stdout so that each address is on a separate line.

In the first invocation of sed, insert each address on a separate line following the regexp `address:`.

In the second invocation of sed remove the old addresses.